# In TPL, how do I override the execution context?

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library, executioncontext

How do I override the execution context when creating a new Task object? I want to use one that I previously captured using ExecutionContext.Capture.

Comment: and on the same day as this post!  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/06/15/executioncontext-vs-synchronizationcontext.aspx

Comment: @JamesManning Yeah I noticed that too. Though I thought it wasn't an coincidence.

Comment: I saw it and realized that it would solve some problems with globals that I'm having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same as you would when not using TPL: using [`ExecutionContext.Run()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.executioncontext.run.aspx). For example:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(
    () => ExecutionContext.Run(
        ec, _ => Console.WriteLine(CallContext.LogicalGetData("foo")), null))
```